# MVC5 override CreateAsync and pass an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am trying to validate if few custom fields exist in the database before creating a new account.  For purpose of demonstrating my problem I will use Email.  Here is my code:

```
public override Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, string password)
{
    if (Users.Any(u => u.Email.Equals(user.Email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        var identityResult = new IdentityResult(new []{"Email exists"});
        return identityResult;
    }
    return base.CreateAsync(user, password);
}
```

So the concept is quite simple, if Email already exists, do not allow user to create the account.  I am trying to move my logic of validation out of the controller into the service.  So the controller calls it like this:

```
var result = await _userService.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

then it does different thing based on result.

The above code won't work, how do I return my error?

`Cannot convert expression type 'IdentityResult' to return type Task<IdentityResult>`

EDIT: I needed to add async word to my CreateAsync method and await the base, so it should be:

```
public override async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, string password)
{
    if (Users.Any(u => u.Email.Equals(user.Email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        var identityResult = new IdentityResult(new []{"Email exists"});
        return identityResult;
    }
    return await base.CreateAsync(user, password);
}
```

Comment: In what sense above code won't work?

Comment: @Evk updated question

Comment: Either not await your _userService.CreateAsync call (just return it directly), or add "async" keyword to your controller method definition (better first).

Comment: My controller already has async `public async Task<ActionResult> Index(RegisterDto model)`

Comment: You call your service (var result = await _userService.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)) from which method? From that Index?

Comment: @Evk I messed up the CreateAsync method, it should of had async keyword in.  I updated the question since I can't post an answer for couple of days.

Comment: So that was exatcly what I meant :) but you really don't need do this - just remove both await and async keywords and return task directly.

Comment: @Evk you said controller, which confused me as this is not in the controller, the call to this method is in the controller.  the base method I am overriding is an async call, I have to await it.  Anyhow, thanks for your help.